# React Native: weird behaviour with TextAlign 'justify' on Android 9

Tags: react-native, text, text-align, justify

I use Android 9 and React Native(expo)'s textAlign 'justify' is supposed to work, and it does in most cases. However I've spotted a weird behaviour that is not that easy to reproduce, but in some cases textAlign 'justify' introduces a unwanted linebreak.

Below a code that does what's expected:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, SafeAreaView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text style={styles.normal_text}>blablablabla super interesting and fun character to play since she can use a lot of different cards for her build, and sometimes adapt her hand to the scenario. However, because she needs careful planning, she’s the </Text>
      <Text style={styles.normal_text}>Lorem Ipsum</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  normal_text: {
    fontSize: 25,
    textAlign: 'justify',
    width:Dimensions.get('window').width - 24,
  },
});
```

Result:

[image: working]

Below a very similar code but a small change in the text makes a difference:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, SafeAreaView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text style={styles.normal_text}>blablabla super interesting and fun character to play since she can use a lot of different cards for her build, and sometimes adapt her hand to the scenario. However, because she needs careful planning, she’s the </Text>
      <Text style={styles.normal_text}>Lorem Ipsum</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  normal_text: {
    fontSize: 25,
    textAlign: 'justify',
    width:Dimensions.get('window').width - 24,
  },
});
```

Result:

[image: not working]

I only removed a 'bla' in the second case and it doesn't work as expected anymore.

Any ideas?

Tank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't just comment so I make an answer.

Just remove the space at the end of your string here:

```
<Text style={styles.normal_text}>
        blablabla super interesting and fun character to play since she can use
        a lot of different cards for her build, and sometimes adapt her hand to
        the scenario. However, because she needs careful planning, she’s the{"HERE"}
      </Text>
```

```
<Text style={styles.normal_text}>
        blablabla super interesting and fun character to play since she can use
        a lot of different cards for her build, and sometimes adapt her hand to
        the scenario. However, because she needs careful planning, she’s the</Text>
```

Comment: Yeah I guess it works for that specific case, but I had the same issue with other texts and they didn't end with a space, so the general problem does not come from here.
Notcie besides that in both cases there's a space at the end, and the behaviour is different.

Comment: The weird thing is that when I auto-formatted your code with my editor, it added braces at the end of your text instead of space, like so: "because she needs careful planning, she’s the{}"